# Django: Retrieve a list of one model property for all distinct values of another property

Tags: python, django, django-models

I’d like to use the Django ORM to give me a list values of a model property for the subset of objects that have a distinct value of another property. Consider a simple model like:

```
class Result(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField()
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

And imagine that I have four results:

```
results = [
    Result(color="blue", score=5), 
    Result(color="blue", score=3), 
    Result(color="red", score=10), 
    Result(color="red", score=8),
]
```

What I'd like to get is something like the following:

```
{
    {"color”: "blue", "scores": [5, 3]}, 
    {"color": "red", "scores": [10, 8]},
}
```

I think it's possible to get there in one shot using Django's aggregation and annotation features, but I'm struggling to figure it out. I know I can get the average score with the following:

```
results.values("color").annotate(avg_score=Avg("score"))
```

If that's possible, then getting the list used to generate the average must also be possible, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly, this will depend on you DB.
If you're using Postgresql you have access to [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg),
so the following will work :

```
results.values("color").annotate(scores=ArrayAgg("score"))
```

You're using MySQL or MariaDB you can use [GroupConcat](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html#django_mysql.models.GroupConcat).
But this won't yield an array, it will yield a string with values separated by commas.
If this field will be manipulated using Python, you can do the following to get an array:

```
my_result.scores.split(",")
```